# Error occurs when trying to delete a window from a Tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, error-handling, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

I created an Entry widget and a Button and added them to a canvas. When I try to remove the two and replace them, I get an error. Here is the code:

```
def change_screen():
    if len(enter_username.get()) == username:
        login_canvas.delete(type_username)
        login_canvas.delete(enter_username)
        login_canvas.create_window(500, 500, window=type_password)
        login_canvas.create_window(500, 600, window=enter_password)


window = Tk()
username = 'cat_lover4'
login_canvas = Canvas(window, width=1440, height=760)
type_username = Entry(window)
type_password = Entry(window)
enter_username = Button(window, text='ENTER', command=change_screen)
enter_password = Button(window, text='ENTER', command=exit)
login_canvas.create_window(500, 500, window=type_username)
login_canvas.create_window(500, 600, window=enter_username)
```

The error is:

```
_tkinter.TclError: invalid boolean operator in tag search expression
```

I initially used widget.destroy(), but the problem with that is I can not use the widget later in the code.
Why does this error occur, and how can I remove a window from a canvas without an error?

Comment: You should use the id returned by `create_window(...)`, like `username_id = login_canvas.create_window(...)`, then you can remove it from canvas by `login_canvas.delete(username_id)`.

Comment: @acw1668 in this case, how would I add username_id to the canvas?